# How to make download button for csv?

Tags: tabulator

I am making a download to CSV button for my table.

I have made a button at the bottom of the table which triggers `down()` function to download.

```js
var tableDataNested = [{
    group: "Backend Engineer A",
    name: "Sourced",
    applied: 300,
    screened: 40,
    interviewed: 5
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer A",
    name: "Referred",
    applied: 3,
    screened: 1,
    interviewed: 0
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer A",
    name: "University",
    applied: 4,
    screened: 2,
    interviewed: 1
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer B",
    name: "Sourced",
    applied: 1000,
    screened: 140,
    interviewed: 55
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer B",
    name: "Referred",
    applied: 30,
    screened: 11,
    interviewed: 2
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer B",
    name: "University",
    applied: 40,
    screened: 22,
    interviewed: 10
  },
];

function down() {
  table.download("csv", "data.csv", {
    delimiter: ","
  });
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tableDataNested,
  dataTree: true,
  dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
  groupBy: "group",
  columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      responsive: 0
    },
    {
      title: "Applied",
      field: "applied",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
    {
      title: "Screened",
      field: "screened",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
    {
      title: "Interviewed",
      field: "interviewed",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
  ],

  footerElement: "<button id='download-csv' onclick='down();'>Download CSV</button>",

});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.3.0/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me

```js
var tableDataNested = [{
    group: "Backend Engineer A",
    name: "Sourced",
    applied: 300,
    screened: 40,
    interviewed: 5
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer A",
    name: "Referred",
    applied: 3,
    screened: 1,
    interviewed: 0
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer A",
    name: "University",
    applied: 4,
    screened: 2,
    interviewed: 1
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer B",
    name: "Sourced",
    applied: 1000,
    screened: 140,
    interviewed: 55
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer B",
    name: "Referred",
    applied: 30,
    screened: 11,
    interviewed: 2
  },
  {
    group: "Backend Engineer B",
    name: "University",
    applied: 40,
    screened: 22,
    interviewed: 10
  },
];

function down() {
  table.download("csv", "data.csv", {
    delimiter: ","
  });
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tableDataNested,
  dataTree: true,
  dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
  groupBy: "group",
  columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      responsive: 0
    },
    {
      title: "Applied",
      field: "applied",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
    {
      title: "Screened",
      field: "screened",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
    {
      title: "Interviewed",
      field: "interviewed",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
  ],

  footerElement: "<button id='download-csv' onclick='down();'>Download CSV</button>",

});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.3.0/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: yeah, it does. That means I did the method correctly. Can you check why it doesn't when I copy your exact code in fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/shq6noc9/1/
That must be the problem for me.

Comment: It works finally. The problem was the order of declaration. First, define the div element where the table will stay. Then, declare & initialize the table.

Comment: Well, carefully looking at CSV downloaded I found that it is not looking like the table with some fields missing. SO, that's not the way.

Comment: Then you should ask a new question

Comment: Well, tried with Tabulator for quite a while without success. Then, I wrote a JSON to CSV converter for myself. Can't rely on frameworks all the time.